# Junos: find out each interface's ip

Tags: ip, switch, juniper, interface, junos

Sorry if my explanation is confusing. 
I need to get all the ip addresses of a Juniper Switch and Router (different models). On Cisco IOS I can get that with `show ip interface brief | exclude unassigned`:

```
cisco_device>show ip interface brief | exclude unassigned
Interface               IP-Address     OK? Method Status     Protocol
TenGigabitEthernet1/30  10.1.1.24      YES NVRAM  up         up      
Loopback0               10.1.95.2      YES NVRAM  up         up      
Port-channel15          10.1.1.150     YES NVRAM  up         up      
Port-channel39          10.2.1.4       YES NVRAM  up         up      
Port-channel100         10.3.1.2       YES NVRAM  up         up      
Vlan49                  10.4.1.40      YES NVRAM  up         up
```

Is there something similar on Junos?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want [`show interfaces`](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-es/junos-es93/junos-es-swcmdref/show-interfaces.html):

```
> show interfaces terse
```

If you want to exclude interfaces without an IP you can match on `inet`:

```
> show interfaces terse | match inet
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the mac address to your command too?

Comment: @Megaslav You'd have to use the non-terse output which outputs the information on multiple lines, which is more difficult to filter.