# Cisco Nexus: list all interfaces with their ips

Tags: networking, ip, switch, interface, cisco-nexus

This is the same as this question, but for Nexus: [Junos: find out each interface's ip](https://serverfault.com/q/480402/151645)

I need to show all interfaces with their respective IPs. I know that on IOS I can get that with `show ip interface brief | exclude unassigned` and on Junos with `show interfaces terse | match inet`.

If I execute `show ip interface brief` on this device, I get an empty output:

```
IP Interface Status for VRF "default"(1)
Interface            IP Address      Interface Status
```

However the device has several Eth interfaces with status up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to issue: `sh ip int brief operational vrf all` to get what you are looking for. What is probably happening is all of your IP addresses are assigned to the "management" VRF and `sh ip interface brief` only shows the default VRF.

When I run the all I get:

```
ny-nexus01# sh ip int brief operational vrf all
IP Interface Status for VRF "management"(2)
Interface            IP Address      Interface Status
mgmt0                10.7.6.5        protocol-up/link-up/admin-up       

IP Interface Status for VRF "default"(1)
Interface            IP Address      Interface Status

ny-nexus01#
```

You can also optionally specify the exact VRF you want, so to get management IPs you would do `sh ip int brief operational vrf management`